# how to stop accepting new requests before closing existing ones?

Tags: node.js, http, https, httpserver

This runs without error:

```
const app = express();

const server = app.listen(3900, '0.0.0.0', () => {
  console.log('listening...');
});

process.once('SIGINT', () => {

  console.log('got SIGINT.')

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('ending process due to SIGINT + subsequent Timeout.')
    process.exit(0);
  }, 3000);

  server.closeIdleConnections();  // <<<
  server.closeAllConnections();  // <<<<

  server.close(err => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
    console.log('closed server, and now shutting down due to SIGINT.')
    process.exit(0);
  });
});
```

but my question is - is this the best way to stop accepting new connections before ending the existing connections/requests?

how are "idle" connections defined?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419909/is-a-question-asking-for-good-ways-to-do-something-really-opinion-based

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is this the best way to stop accepting new connections before ending the existing connections/requests?

I guess "best" is subjective and it depends on the application. However, calling the *synchronous* `server.closeAllConnections()` before allowing the *asynchronous* `server.close()` to finish it's work is not the most graceful way to stop any ongoing connections (those currently sending a request or waiting for a response). In short, I would say **no** this is not the most graceful way to stop accepting new connections before ending existing connections due to the abrupt nature of `closeAllConnections`.

> how are "idle" connections defined?

I'll link you to [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/http.html#servercloseidleconnections) which states that idle connections are **connections connected to this server which are not sending a request or waiting for a response**.

To make your `SIGINT` handler more graceful, I would recommend a slight modification by removing the call to `server.closeAllConnections()` and nesting your `setTimeout` inside of the `close` callback. Something along these lines:

```js
process.once('SIGINT', () => {
  /**
   * Immediately close any idle connections.
   * May not be strictly necessary since as of Node v19.0.0
   * server.close() will also close idle connections before
   * returning / firing the 'close' event.
   * 
   * Either way, it may reduce the workload of server.close()
   * by minimizing the connections it must close or wait to
   * finish to those that were already active, or only created
   * in the short time span between calling closeIdleConnections()
   * and close().
   */
  server.closeIdleConnections()

  // Now stop the server from accepting new connections while keeping existing connections.
  server.close((err) => {
    // Force close all connections after a specified timeout
    setTimeout(() => {
      server.closeAllConnections()
      process.exit(0)
    }, 3000).unref() // prevents the event loop from remaining active so your server can shutdown earlier if this timeout is not needed.
  })
})
```

Note, that the callback to `server.close` will only receive an error if you are attempting to shutdown a server that was not running. This is noted in the documentation for [`net.Server.close()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html#serverclosecallback).

Comment: take a look at the golang code in my answer and see what the apis for those say - I am looking for the equivalent in nodejs

Comment: I believe I just gave it to you. Is there a reason you suggest otherwise? Node is not go so it won’t look the same, however the desired behavior you describe is there.

Comment: maybe so, I will test it out, will upvote at least

Comment: The thing to note, is that calling `close()` **stops the server from accepting new connections** which is what you were asking for. Within the callback provided to `close` you can choose to forcefully close any existing connections with `closeAllConnections()` either after a timeout or not. However, the callback is not expected to be invoked until all the connections have already ended, so technically existing connections should already have ended by the time the callback runs. One thing you might want to pay more attention to are keep-alive connections.

Comment: haven't tested it but the explanation makes sense, so I will accept it

Comment: maybe close idle connections in the same tick as all connections? not sure if the idle connections thing is useful at all. but it seems to make sense to stop accepting new connects before doing anything else

Comment: Thus my lengthy comment before calling `closeIdleConnections`. Only way to know for sure is testing (and possibly reading the node source code). FWIW calling `close` also ends idle connections.

Comment: yeah I see, hmmm, strange, there should be a pretty good formula for clean shutdown, never thought about it much, but for prod, would like to allow any existing requests to have a chance at clean finish

Answer (score 0):

In golang, we can do this:

```
server := &http.Server{
      // ...
}

listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", addr)
```

and then do this:

```
if err := listener.Close(); err != nil { // Stop listening for new connections
      // err
}
if err := server.Close(); err != nil { // Close all current/existing connections
       // err
}
```

the first call stops accepting new connections, the second call, closes all existing connections. It's nice to have them separate, but not sure how to do this with node.js

Answer (score 0):

> but my question is - is this the best way to stop accepting new connections before ending the existing connections/requests?

You didn't quality 'best', but lets assume you want to gracefully shut down a HTTP server, without interrupting in-flight connections because new ones are spinning up.

`closeAllConnections()` will interupt any in-flight connections, so don't call that.

> how are "idle" connections defined?

Idle connections are TCP connections that are opened by a HTTP client but aren't currently sending a HTTP request or waiting for a HTTP response. These are safe to close usually.

Comment: yeah see the golang example (in my "answer"), it seems ideal to stop accepting any new connections and then close the existing ones in that order. not sure how to do that with node.js